# How to fix java error in Codename One : error: package java.security.spec does not exist?

Tags: java, codenameone, java-security

I'm starting to use Codename One, but I got the following error :

```
 error: package java.security.spec does not exist
```

I need to do encryption/decryption.

I took a closer look at the JavaDocs, in jdk8, there is the security package, but in Codename One, it's missing, as seen in the image below, so how to get it fixed ? Any sample code ?

[image]

Comment: This package seems to have been around since Java 1.2, so if it doesn't exist that means your code isn't being compiled with a JDK properly.

Comment: My code was from another Netbeans project I have, it compiled and run properly in that project, but after I copied the file into the new Codename One project, it caused error, I haven't changed a single line.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have those packages as they are pretty problematic in their design and pose export restrictions. We have different packages to implement various encryption tasks in the Bouncy Castle cn1lib which you can find in the Extensions section.

I'm afraid you will need to adapt the code related to the encryption to use these API's or port the Java SE API's from an open source implementation e.g. Android. However, the latter isn't trivial as those classes do feature a lot of indirection.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me a simple example of how to encrypt/decrypt a string [ i.e. "ABCD" ] and save/load a encrypted message to a file ? Or point me to any sample code ?

Comment: There are several examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcodenameone%5D+encrypt and in the discussion forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codenameone-discussions you can also use our encrypted storage feature to encrypt everything https://www.codenameone.com/blog/seamless-storage-encryption.html